# Accessing a Ruby hash with a variable as the key

Tags: ruby

If I had the following ruby hash:

```
environments = {
   'testing' =>  '11.22.33.44',
   'production' => '55.66.77.88'
}
```

How would I access parts of the above hash? An example below as to what I am trying to achieve.

```
current_environment = 'testing'
"rsync -ar root@#{environments[#{testing}]}:/htdocs/"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to `exec` that last line, as it's obviously a shell command rather than Ruby code.  You don't need to interpolate twice; once will do:

```
exec("rsync -ar root@#{environments['testing']}:/htdocs/")
```

Or, using the variable:

```
exec("rsync -ar root@#{environments[current_environment]}:/htdocs/")
```

Note that the more Ruby way is to use Symbols rather than Strings as the keys:

```
environments = {
   :testing =>  '11.22.33.44',
   :production => '55.66.77.88'
}

current_environment = :testing
exec("rsync -ar root@#{environments[current_environment]}:/htdocs/")
```

Answer (score 5):

You would use brackets:

```
environments = {
   'testing' =>  '11.22.33.44',
   'production' => '55.66.77.88'
}
myString = 'testing'
environments[myString] # => '11.22.33.44'
```